Transit visa required for South Korea?
I am a Myanmar passport holder and I am flying back from USA (JFK) to Thailand with Korean Air. I have a layover in Korea for 5 hours. Do I need a transit visa for my case? My baggages are all checked through so I do not need to go through Immigration.

Does this answer your question? Is there any online resource that can tell me what visa rules are for passport holders of a specific country?
